# Python creating Base64 key and calling an API

Tags: python

Assuming I have the following variables:

```
userVar = ABC
passVar = XYZ
```

I am familiar with this method of inserting the username and password directly but how can I use variable?

```
userAndPass = b64encode(b"ABC:XYZ").decode("ascii")
headerBasic = {'Authorization': 'Basic %s' % userAndPass}
```

This gives me the headerBasic which then I call use as a header in my API Get.  How can I not insert my username and password --> b64encode(b"ABC:XYZ")
I have tried to create a string like this:

```
str2 = userVar+":"+ passVar
userAndPass = b64encode(b"str2").decode("ascii")
```

it wont work.

Comment: what do you mean *it wont work*? What is the error message?

Comment: Change `b"str2"` to `str2.encode()`.

Comment: Thank  you now it works